# Auth0 UserProvider with NextJS app router

Tags: next.js, auth0, next-auth

I'm rewriting my company's whole React application onto **NextJS 13.4.8** using app/ directory. We are using Auth0 as an auth provider (no plans for NextAuth) and from the documentation of the `nextjs-auth` with app router (currently in beta, https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/tree/beta#app-router)  I assume it should work... somehow. As of now, it is a plain NextJS app so it's an open sandbox.

The problem is that the app itself compiles but when going to the browser I'm having the following error:

```
- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth0')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth0+nextjs-auth0@2.6.3_next@13.4.8/node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/handlers/auth.js:49:47)
    at step (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/.pnpm/tslib@2.6.0/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.mjs:260:23)
    at Object.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/.pnpm/tslib@2.6.0/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.mjs:201:20)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/.pnpm/tslib@2.6.0/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.mjs:179:71)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

I've done the following (with the use of docs on their gh):

- created `app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.ts`

```js
// app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.ts
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export const GET = handleAuth();
```

- wrapped `RootLayout` with `UserProvider` from `@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client`

```js
// src/app/layout.tsx
import './globals.css';
import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export const metadata = {
  ...
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <html lang='en'>
        <body>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

- on `login` page I'm returning `<a href='/api/auth/login'` - `'use client'` is present there

```js
// src/app/login/page.tsx
'use client'
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';
...

export default function Login() {
  ...
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();
  ...
  return (
    <a href='/api/auth/login'>
      <Button size='lg'>
         Login
      </Button>
    </a>
  )
}
```

- inside `.env.local` there are: `AUTH0_SECRET`, `AUTH0_BASE_URL`, `AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL`, `AUTH0_CLIENT_ID` and `AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET` taken from the Auth0 dashboard - this data is the same as in the *old* React app

Is there something wrong with my solution, or there is a bug in this integration, or maybe there is some other problem that you see here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by upgrading my auth0 @auth0/nextjs-auth0 to 3.0.0-beta.3

Try this

```
npm i @auth0/nextjs-auth0@3.0.0-beta.3
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/nextjs-auth0?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 0):

make the route:

```
app/api/auth/route.ts
```

not

```
app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain your issue is/was that you are using `import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';` (e.g.; the client-side package) from your `src/app/layout.tsx` file, which is not, or at least from the provided code does not seem to be, flagged as `use client`, and hence is on the server-side of the setup.

You can fix it by using the `UserProvider` in a client side component (possibly just a child of your `layout.tsx` but marked as `use client`).